# Is sub-domain considered cross-domain?

Tags: javascript, html

Is http://nonsecure.form.xyz.org and https://secure.form.xyz.org considered different domain? I am asking this because my javascript in secure one cannot call it's parent. Secure domain is inside non-secure domain through an iframe.

**EDIT**

**Conclusion**

You can perform cross-domain scripting but cannot perform cross-protocol scripting (e.g. https and http)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do here is set `document.domain = "form.xyz.org"` on both sides before attempting any cross-domain scripting.

**However, you cannot cross-script between different protocols.**

Comment: I tried it but still doesn't work. The problem seems to be between http and https. Does document.domain resolve that as well?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. No, you cannot cross-script between different protocols.